# InvokeCommand from Observable.Timer causes cross-thread issue

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveCommand that refreshes data and is bound to a Button in XAML. The functionality works fine, but I also want to execute the command on a timer.

I have the following code - SetupAutoRefresh is called from the ctor in my VM, but when the Observable fires, I get an exception with the message: *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."*

VM:

```
private void SetupAutoRefresh() {
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .InvokeCommand(RefreshData);

    RefreshData = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(Refresh);
}

private async Task Refresh()
{
    var updatedData = await _repository.GetAll();
    Data.Merge(updatedData);
}

private ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> _refreshData;
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> RefreshData
{
    get { return _refreshData; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _refreshData, value); }
}

private IReactiveList<Model> _data;
public IReactiveList<Model> Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _data, value); }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2"
        Command="{Binding RefreshData}"
        Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonTheme}"
        Content="{StaticResource RefreshToolbarIcon}"
        ToolTip="Refresh Search"/>
```

Debug output provides this stacktrace:

> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.get_Command()
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateCanExecute()
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object >sender, EventArgs e)
>     at 
>    System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteChangedEventManager.HandlerSink.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged() in C:\projects\reactiveui\src\ReactiveUI\ReactiveCommand.cs:line 628

I've tried many different variations of attempting to schedule this on the RxApp.MainThreadScheduler but without any joy - ObserveOn, SubscribeOn, setting the output scheduler... none of which I had much hope for anyway.

Feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but have been banging my head against a brick wall for the whole afternoon. Surely this scenario is possible in RxUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue - looks like the Observable needed to be created on the UI thread. I missed it from the original post, but the SetupAutoRefresh method had  been called from another async method, which had switched context during a prior await.

Answer (score 0):

The `Refresh` method runs on a background thread; you can't modify databound properties within that method.

Try this:

```
private void SetupAutoRefresh() {
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            // remove ObserveOn here; the Command will run on the background
            .InvokeCommand(RefreshData);

    RefreshData = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(Refresh);
    // RefreshData.Subscribe is guaranteed to run on the UI thread
    RefreshData.Subscribe(listOfModels => Data.Merge(listOfModels))
}

private async Task Refresh()
{
    // all this method does is deliver a list of models
    return await _repository.GetAll();
}

// return IEnumerable<Model> from the command
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IEnumerable<Model>> RefreshData
```

Now, your `ReactiveCommand` simply fetches the new data, and returns it to you on the UI thread within `Subscribe` :)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this too - but it doesn't work as it doesn't address the underlying issue. It's not the databound properties that it's complaining about, but the command bound to the button. Specifically when CanExecute has changed (presumably to false) during the command's execution. See the stacktrace in my original post.

Comment: Okay, so I've copied your original code and made up the dependencies ([MainViewModel.cs](https://gist.github.com/domyd/73895b166b160b9d09d5902e24bd97ef), [MainWindow.xaml](https://gist.github.com/domyd/350e8aef743d348e183b5c496391e220)). This works perfectly for me; the only thing I changed was swapping the `Observable` and `ReactiveCommand` creation order in `SetupAutoRefresh`, otherwise it would crash. Also I replaced `Merge` with `Add`. Maybe that helps?